# Change column into row in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I've data in a SQL table in the below layout.

| Var Name | Time Stamp | Value | Validity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample 1 | 10/16/2023 12:10:06 PM | 100.0 | 1 |
| Sample 2 | 10/16/2023 12:10:06 PM | 180.0 | 1 |
| Sample 1 | 10/16/2023 12:11:06 PM | 120.0 | 1 |
| Sample 2 | 10/16/2023 12:11:06 PM | 178.0 | 1 |

My requirement is to produce the following layout. I'm unable to write my query as I've no idea how to begin.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
I'm using MS Report Builder for the query.

| Time Stamp | Sample 1 Value | Sample 1 Validity | Sample 2 Value | Sample 2 Validity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/16/2023 12:10:06 PM | 100.0 | 1 | 120.0 | 1 |
| 10/16/2023 12:11:06 PM | 180.0 | 1 | 178.0 | 1 |

Comment: *"I'm unable to write my query as I've no clue how to begin."* Search pivoting/conditional aggregation/Cross Tab.